# Trouble getting test user information

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use the Facebook SDK 5.2.1 to ultimately create a test user, however even what I believe is the simple example of getting the list of test accounts isn't working for me. I get the OAuthException "An access token is required to request this resource."

Here's my code (replace APP ID and APP SECRET with my own):

```
FacebookOAuthClient oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient { AppId = "APP ID", AppSecret = "APP SECRET" };
dynamic tokenRes = oauth.GetApplicationAccessToken();
fbClient = new FacebookClient(tokenRes.access_token);

 dynamic response = fbClient.Get("APPID/accounts/test-users");
```

However, I get the exception on the fbClient.Get line.

Any idea as to what's wrong?

Thanks,
Chad

Comment: I also simply tried without using FacebookOAuthClient, just to create a FacebookClient passing in my app ID and app secret into the constructor. That's didn't work either :(

Comment: You tried the code in my answer?  What does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of trying various things and reading various web pages/blogs, I found the reason it wasn't working. In my app settings, I had my app type set to a Native/Desktop App. Changing this to Web, allows the above scenario to work. I'm not yet quite sure of what other differences exist between web vs native facebook apps. My app is certainly only being used via a desktop application and I can't understand why I need to set this to Web just to allow me to create test users.

Answer (score 0):

This code works in my app:

```
var app = new FacebookClient(FacebookApplication.Current.AppId,
    FacebookApplication.Current.AppSecret);

dynamic result = app.Post(string.Format("{0}/accounts/test-users",
    FacebookApplication.Current.AppId),
    new { installed = true, permissions = "user_about_me" });
```

Comment: I did get it working after changing my app settings (see my answer). Curious, I never understood how to use the FacebookApplication class. How do you get it initialized?

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you are receiving the exception `OAuthException` is because you have not yet got the permission of the user.

To do a Graph API call on the current user, you need to get the user to accept the permissions that you require FIRST and then do the Graph API call.

You need to get the user to a browser some how in your application, as there is not an authentication flow which doesn't require a browser window.

Check out this URL to view the authentication flows:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Right, I understand the concept of requiring the user to accept permissions first but I don't see how the session is used.

I tried to add the code I posted to the flow within the Facebook SDK WinForm sample whereby the user logs in first but that ran into the same problem.

For example, in the webBrowser_Navigated event, if I copy & paste, the code I posted when the FacebookOAuthResult is successful, I still get the same problem. I create a FacebookClient obj using my app ID & secret. Does it have to link somehow to the FacebookOAuthResult?

Comment: One other point: Even if I try to use the Facebook Graph API Explorer and put my app's access token (from the access token tool) in the access token field and request the APPID/accounts/test-users as p;art of the GET url, I get the same OAuthException returned: "An access token is required to request this resource."

I can however view/create test users through the facebook app's dashboard interface.

Comment: downvoted for failing to comprehend the question.  It is not a user request, it is an app request.